# How do I cover a 2D array of colors with the fewest possible colored rectangles?

Tags: image-processing, pixel, game-development

I'm creating a game that takes an image represented by a 16x16 array of html color codes and creates a 3D object made out of rectangular cuboids. Like taking the Paint program on Windows and extruding your image into the Z axis.

```
// An image containing 16 columns and 16 rows of hexcodes for 256 total hexcodes
[ [ "#FF5733", "#FF5733", "#FF5733", "#FF5733", ... ], [ "#FF5733", ... ] ]
```

**How can I create the smallest possible array of rectangles that would cover the image without creating overlapping rectangles?**

```
// Rectangles that represent the 2D image, a blank image would have only one rectangle
rectangles = [{
 color = "#FF5733",
 x = 5,
 y = 3,
 width = 5,
 height = 5,
}, ... ]
```

My first attempt at a solution --- every single pixel in the 16x16 image getting a cube (256 cubes) --- created huge load times (30 seconds) for loading 500x 3D images.

One improvement I was able to make was "reading on" past the current color in the row until I hit a different color or the end of the row in order to create long rectangular cuboids across the row. This improvement cut the cuboid count in half. Extending this trick across the y axis has proven difficult. Overlapping rectangles look really ugly.

My understanding is that this problem is NP Hard. I'd be happy if we had a solution that had fewer rectangles even if its not provably the fewest rectangles.

The [Wiki Article on the problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_covering#Covering_a_rectilinear_polygon_with_rectangles) does not give any concrete suggestions.

Comment: you want an "approximation", not the perfect solution. that's the keyword to go looking for approaches. I also doubt you need the general *polygon* formulation of the problem. you have a 2D area and need to **partition** that into rectangles, right? cover allows overlap, you don't want "cover". since this isn't strictly programming, but geometry/math/logic/computer science, I'd recommend a *stack exchange* with focus on that instead.

Comment: This has been immensely helpful, thanks!